# ionic angular data binding error

Tags: angular, ionic3

**hello  every one please am  in the process of learning  ionic  am having aproblem to display my results of an api (last fm )  i console.log the data without any problem but when it comes to bind it it get errors 
here my template** 
**results.html**

```
<ion-navbar  color="dark">
    <ion-title>results</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content  class="home">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item text-wrap >
          {{artist | json}}
        <ion-avatar item-left>        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>
            {{artist.bio}}
        </h2>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

**here is my results.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MusicserviceProvider } from '../../providers/musicservice/musicservice';
import {Artist} from '../../pages/models/artist.interface';  

/**
 * Generated class for the ResultsPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-results',
  templateUrl: 'results.html',
})
export class ResultsPage {
 artistname:String;
 artist:Artist;
 loading:any;

  constructor(private musicservice:MusicserviceProvider,private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, private loadingCtrl :LoadingController) {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: `
      <ion-spinner ></ion-spinner>`
    });


  }

getUserInformation():void {
  this.musicservice.getArtiseInfo(this.artistname).subscribe((data => this.artist = data));
  console.log(this.artist);

}


  ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.artistname = this.navParams.get('artistname');
  if(this.artistname)
  this.getUserInformation() ;
 }

}
```

**and here is my services**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http ,Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/Observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/Observable/throw';

import {Artist} from '../../pages/models/artist.interface';  

@Injectable()
export class MusicserviceProvider {
  private base_url :String ="http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist";
  private base_url2 :String ="api_key=b016b736378ec88dc30c36e4cc6e936b&format=json";

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello MusicserviceProvider Provider');
  }

  getArtiseInfo(artist:String):Observable<Artist>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.base_url}=${artist}&${this.base_url2}`)
    //.do((data:Response)=> console.log(data))
    .map((data:Response) => data.json())
   // .do((data:Response)=> console.log(data))
    .catch((error:Response) =>Observable.throw(error.json().error || "server error")) 
  }
}
```

i get the results as i said the problem comes i the display so much ..
thanks waiting

Comment: what error does it show?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You could also try e using {{ artist?.bio}}  in your template

Comment: i tried that  but is not giving

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the view is loaded before the value is obtained from the http call.You have to wait for the data to come in before rendering the template.You can do this by

1. Declare a class boolean property

   ```
   private isDataAvailable:boolean=false;
   ```
2. Make this variable true once the data is available.

   ```
   getUserInformation(): void {
    this.musicservice.getArtiseInfo(this.artistname).subscribe((data => {
        this.artist = data;
        this.isDataAvailable = true;

    }));
    console.log(this.artist);

   }
   ```

3.Render the template only when the data is available;

```
<ion-content  class="home" *ngIf="isDataAvailable">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item text-wrap > <!-- You can as well do *ngIf="artist?" here instead..-->
          {{artist | json}}
        <ion-avatar item-left>        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>
            {{artist.bio}}
        </h2>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

You can as well use async pipe for the same.You can read about it [here](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help  but i tried what  u gave but nothing changed